# How to use Linq to join multiple DataTables on multiple columns containing DBNull values

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

I have 3 DataTable objects with relational data that I want to join.
The first has a schema that looks like

```
DataTable parent = new DataTable();
parent.Columns.Add("Id1", typeof(string));
parent.Columns.Add("Id2", typeof(string));
// more metadata
```

Where either of the Ids may be DBNull, but not both.

The two chlid tables have the same schema.

```
DataTable child = new DataTable();
child.Columns.Add("Id1", typeof(string));
child.Columns.Add("Id2", typeof(string));
child.Columns.Add("BeginDate", typeof(DateTime));
child.Columns.Add("SomeData", typeof(float));
// more data
```

I have a function that takes all three DataTables as inputs, and is supposed to return the joined table.

```
var dataToReturn =  // will be converted to a DataTable later.
    from
        p in parent.AsEnumerable()
    join c1 in child1.AsEnumerable()
        on new {
            Id1 = p["Id1"],
            Id2 = p["Id2"],
        }
        equals new {
            Id1 = c1["Id1"],
            Id2 = c1["Id2"],
        }
    join c2 in child2.AsEnumerable()
        on new {
            Id1 = p["Id1"],
            Id2 = p["Id2"],
            BeginDate = c1["BeginDate"],
        }
        equals new {
            Id1 = p["Id1"],
            Id2 = p["Id2"],
            BeginDate = c1["BeginDate"],
        }
    select new {
        Id1 = p["Id1"],
        Id2 = p["Id2"],
        BeginDate = c1["BeginDate"],
        Child1Data = c1["SomeData"],
        Child2Data = c2["SomeData"],
    }
```

However, this returns no results, even though there are many non-null values matching on those conditions.

If I were writing SQL (with "is not distinct from" from Postgres to make null = null return true for brevity), I would write

```
select
    p.Id1,
    p.Id2,
    c1.BeginDate,
    c1.SomeData as Child1Data,
    c2.SomeData as Child2Data
from
    Parent p
    join Child1 c1
        on c1.Id1 is not distinct from p.Id1
        and c1.Id2 is not distinct from p.Id2
    join Child2 c2
        on c2.Id1 is not distinct from p.Id1
        and c2.Id2 is not distinct from p.Id2
        and c2.BeginDate = c1.BeginDate
```

Notice the use of "is not distinct from" over "=" for the Id fields, since I want "DBNull.Value == DBNull.Value" to return true.

My questions:

Is this possible to do with in-memory DataTables with Linq?
How does Linq handle DBNull.Value comparisons in these queries?

Comment: In order to return something, the LINQ query must compile (the posted doesn't). Other than that, it should work. If it doesn't, please post [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Linq will match `DBNull.Value` to another `DBNull.Value` correctly. I believe that was your question and not joining a second child table as this is trivial

```
DataTable parent = new DataTable();
parent.Columns.Add("Id1", typeof(string));
parent.Columns.Add("Id2", typeof(string));
DataRow r1 = parent.NewRow();
r1["Id1"] = "1";
r1["Id2"] = DBNull.Value;
parent.Rows.Add(r1);
DataRow r3 = parent.NewRow();
r3["Id1"] = "1";
r3["Id2"] = "2";
parent.Rows.Add(r3);

DataTable child1 = new DataTable();
child1.Columns.Add("Id1", typeof(string));
child1.Columns.Add("Id2", typeof(string));
child1.Columns.Add("BeginDate", typeof(DateTime));
child1.Columns.Add("SomeData", typeof(float));
DataRow r2 = child1.NewRow();
r2["Id1"] = "1";
r2["Id2"] = DBNull.Value;
child1.Rows.Add(r2);
DataRow r4 = child1.NewRow();
r4["Id1"] = "1";
r4["Id2"] = "2";
child1.Rows.Add(r4);

var dataToReturn =
    from
    p in parent.AsEnumerable()
    join c1 in child1.AsEnumerable()
    on new { Id1 = p["Id1"], Id2 = p["Id2"] }
    equals new { Id1 = c1["Id1"], Id2 = c1["Id2"] }
    select new
    {
        Id1 = p["Id1"],
        Id2 = p["Id2"]
    };

foreach(var l in dataToReturn)
{
    Console.WriteLine(l.Id1 + "|" + l.Id2);
}

Console.ReadKey();
```

Output:

```
1|
1|2
```

Comment: You're correct. Matching on DBNull.Value works by default. @Ivan Stoev is also correct in that the code I posted should work. I finally found the problem. The child table sources were CSV, and the parent's JSON. One of the Ids for the JSON file was wrapped in double quotes. My method to convert the CSV to a DataTable removes the quotes, but the JSON deserializer did not. Id != "Id". Thanks for the help!